# SQL - how do I include views in queries?

Tags: sql

So I have the tables Book (primary key bookid, secondary keys - publisherid, authorid and stockid), and the tables Publisher, Author and Stock, with their respective primary keys being the ID ones. I need to create the view infopressstock which would show only the books in stock with the publisher name Infopress. I also have the views Books in stock which has two columns, one with the title of the book and the other with the number of copies in stock, and BPA, which has three columns, book, publisher and author. However I can't figure out how to implement this in order to work, with the solution I have now it shows the number of Infopress books to be 0.

```
  CREATE VIEW infopressstock AS
        SELECT COUNT(instock) AS "stock total"
           FROM Book INNER JOIN Stock ON Book.BookID = Stock.BookID
               INNER JOIN Publisher ON Book.PublisherID = Publisher.PublisherID
        WHERE publisher.name = 'Infopress';
```

Comment: In a select statement a view acts no differently than a table does. `from viewname` instead of `from tablename`. I am not sure if that is what you are asking or if you are unclear on your business requirements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: There are two types of tables: _base tables_ and _views_. You query them both in the same way. (Sometimes you don't even know if it's a base table or a view.)

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing this exercise.

By using the views BPA and BooksInStock, create a new view that displays the total number of books published by Info Press that are currently in stock. Name the view InfoPressStock. Again, see the view's result table below: The result attribute is named "stock total".

Not the best answer but works:

```
CREATE VIEW InfoPressStock AS
        SELECT sum(instock) AS "stock total"
           FROM stock 
           INNER JOIN book ON stock.bookid = book.bookid
           WHERE book.bookid = 103 OR book.bookid = 111 OR book.bookid = 105
```